# ActionScript: extract / modify frames from video / NetStream

Tags: video, actionscript, frames, netstream

I want to modify all the frames loaded from NetStream before playing them out.
Is there any possible way? better with build-in classes and methods, or 3rd-party lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var frames:Vector.<bitmap>; 
onEnterFrame(event:Event) : void {
    frames.add(video);
}
```

Briefly speaking, play the video, then record it in the handler of EnterFrame event.
But this way has many disanvatages...though.